# bash: /bin/sed: Argument list too long

Tags: bash, sed, command-line

I have two files. 
The first (emails) should be cleaned according to the second (domains).
First is 15 GB, second is 160 MB.

```
dom=`cat file2.txt | xargs | sed -e "s/ /|/g"` ; sed -r "/$dom/d" file1.txt >> final_file.txt
```

This command gives me `bash: /bin/sed: Argument list too long`.

Comment: Posting sample contents of the two files, and at least some of `dom`, and the size of `dom`, would help. Being as you say file2 is 160mb and your first sed deletes nothing, I assume dom is also 160MB. And then you pass that as a single arg to sed. That's your issue -- one huge arg in the /../d command. Passing sed a multi-megabyte regex is not going to end well, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you just want:

```
grep -Fvf file2.txt file1.txt > final_file.txt
```

That is store in `final_file.txt` the lines of `file1.txt` that contain none of the lines of `file2.txt`.

Add the `-x` option if you want the lines of `file1.txt` that are not in `file2.txt`. Or `-w` to match on *words* (where `bar.com` would not match in `foobar.com` or `bar.common`, but would still match in `foo.bar.com.us` for instance).

But if we're talking gigabytes of data and megabytes of different strings to look for, even that is going to take ages.

A faster approach with a shell like `ksh`, `zsh` or `bash` with support for process substitution would be:

```
export LC_ALL=C
comm -23 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) > final_file.txt
```

Now if as you clarified in comments, `file2.txt` is meant to be a list of domains and you mean to filter out of `file1.txt` the lines that end in `@` followed by any of those domains, then a more efficient approach would be to use a hash table:

```
awk -F@ '
  ! domains_processed {excluded[$0]; next}
  ! ($NF in excluded)
  ' file2.txt domains_processed=1 file1.txt > final_file.txt
```

Problems with your approach:

- useless use of `cat` (UUOC). `cat` is to concatenate files. It makes little sense for a single file. You can use `xargs < file` or `< file xargs` for `xargs` stdin to be directly the file instead of a pipe from a `cat` process which just shoves the contents of the file.
- `xargs` calls `echo` by default. While `echo` joins its arguments with space characters, which you want here, it also performs other things the list of which depends on the implementation. Also `xargs` expects the input in a very specific format. Here I'd expect you want each of the line of `file2.txt` to be passed as a separate argument to `echo` for which you'd need the GNU-specific `xargs -rd '\n'`. Also `xargs` will run `echo` as many times as necessary to avoid the limit of the size  of arguments. So the output of `xargs` will have several lines for a 160MB input.

  To join the lines of a file with a specific character, the command is `paste`:

  ```
  paste -sd '|' file2.txt
  ```
- Here, you're building a regex for `sed -r` (`-r` being a GNU extension) by joining those words with `|`, but you're not escaping the regexp operators found in those lines. If those are meant  to be domain names, then note that `.` is a regexp operators which matches any character. You'd have bigger problems with other characters. That `sed "/$dom/r"` would be an arbitrary command execution vulnerability if you didn't have full control over the contents of `file2.txt`.
- If `file2.txt` is 160MB large, then so will be `$dom` (more or less). Sizes of command lines is limited. On Linux, the size of a single argument is also limited (to 128KiB), so you can't pass the `sed` script via arguments. It would have to be passed with `-f`.

Comment: hello mate! yes, I want lines of file1.txt which are not in file2.txt, the problem is file1 contain emails(jonny@gmail.com) and file2 contain domains (gmail.com etc). Will it work? thx!

Comment: @Jonny, if that's a substring match, the `comm` / `grep -x` would not work. But then the question is if `file2` contains `gmail.com`, should `foo@bigmail.com`, `bar@foo.gmail.com`, `blah@foo.gmailling.uk` be excluded?

Comment: only `@gmail.com` should be excluded, without subdomains

Comment: @Jonny, see edit.